# How to add res folder to 'androidTest'?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have Android Studio 1.1-beta.4, and I want to add a `res` folder to my `androidTest` directory? Whenever I try to do so (via right-clicking, and so on) I'm only able to add to either `debug`, `main`, or `release` sourceset.

Essentially, I want to have:

```
project/app/src/main/res/<resource_folders>
project/app/src/androidTest/res/<resource_folder>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Project tab select the Android view (normally this is of default). Right click on any folder: New >>> Folder >>> Res Folder. Since the res folder in the main it's already there and you want the resource test folder click in the popup wizard "Change folder location" and enter "src/test/res". And click Finish. :)

Comment: I don't see anything called "change folder location"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project=>new =>folder =>Select Res Folder, it will automatically add res folder in your project.

Comment: Here's the problem with that: it'll only let me add into `main` sourceset (if I select either `debug` or `release`, it'll create the respective directories). Any ideas?

Comment: can you try this manually in your source just copy paste res folder n check i'm not sure may be it will work....

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2. Instead of creating the folder with the given options in the Android Studio, I used the terminal.

1. Open a terminal in your project folder.
2. `cd app/src/test` to navigate to the test folder.
3. `mkdir resources` to create the resources folder.

After that, the resources folder will appear in the project manager and should be able to create subfolders and add files to it.

[image]

You can check that the folder has been correctly added to the path by copying the full path:

[image]